# Spring annotations basic question

Tags: spring, annotations

As far as I understand, main purpose of dependency injection is to have all dependencies separated declaratively, so that we can easily review and change the dependency structure easily...right?

Then by using dependency annotations spread through out the code, aren't we just going back to non-centralized system (similar to simple new operator), which is harder to tweak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Autowired`/`@Inject` annotations usually declare dependencies on interfaces rather than on concrete classes (as in the case of `new`), thus you still can control which implementations should be injected by controlling which beans are declared in the context. Also, these dependencies can be overriden manually.

`@Component`-family annotations can be controlled as well, since you can exclude particular classes from component scanning.

Comment: May be I am dumb, but I m not fully convinced. "...thus you still can control which implementations should be injected by controlling which beans are declared in the context". Its not that much flexible compare to xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of dependency injection is to decouple the declaration of dependencies from the actual satisfying of those dependencies.  How the declaration is done is an orthogonal issue.

`@Autowired` is a form of dependency declaration.  Using `@Autowired` supports encapsulation.  A class' injected dependencies are documented directly in the code instead of in another file.

Answer (score 0):

These types of discussions have tendency to become religious so I'll stear clear of the "main purpose" definition and the semantics of whether this or that pattern is really and truly fulfilled.

I try to look at it like a tool that can offer certain features. For instance, using Spring (DI) is a good way to separate interfaces and implementations. Users of a particular interface need not know how to create the implementation (or where it resides). This is often something good. Using Spring also enables a whole lot of other stuff: AOP and AOP-driven features like transaction handling, scopeing and a whole bunch of pre-built integrations to other frameworks and technologies. Annotations make a lot of this easier and clearer and best of all, I don't have to use them where it's not practical or possible - there is always the option to configure it in XML instead.